# How to infer translate, shear, etc from manual matrix operations?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation

While reading some code from UCMerced's TriPath Toolkit, I came across these

```
float xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax; 
float mat[16] = { 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1 };
TheLct->get_bounds ( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax );
glMatrixMode ( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity ();

float width = xmax-xmin;
float height = ymax-ymin;
mat[0]=mat[5]=mat[10]= 1.8f * (1 / (width > height ? width : height));
glMultMatrixf ( mat );
mat[0]=mat[5]=mat[10]= 1;

mat[12]=-(xmin+w/2);
mat[13]=-(ymin+h/2);
glMultMatrixf ( mat );
```

In the first transformation, the first three diagonal `1`'s in the matrix are multiplied by a factor. From my limited knowledge of the identity matrix, this appears to be scaling by a factor.

The second transformation, however, I don't really understand:

```
mat[12]=-(xmin+w/2);
mat[13]=-(ymin+h/2);
glMultMatrixf ( mat );
```

First of all, I don't know what it even means to change indices `12` and `13` in such a matrix. I'm trying to figure it out by reading the wikipedia page on transformations, but I guess I don't have enough math-related domain knowledge to make sense of it.

Whereas the OpenGL resources I can find don't really seem to modify matrices in this manner, rather they use functions like `glScaleF`.

How can I relate manual matrix transformations such as the above to scaling, shearing, translating, and rotating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first matrix, as you correctly guessed, is a uniform scale matrix. The second matrix is just a translation (along x and y axis). Note that the (fixed function matrix stack of the) GL 
uses a column major memory layout, where the translation part is always in `m[12]`, `m[13]`, `m[14]` (see also [answer 9.005 in the old GL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0005)). The combined transformation is not a perspective projection (that would require that `(m[3], m[7], m[11])` is not the null vector), but an orthogonal one.

For an easy explanation of how all these numbers can be geometrically interpreted, you might find [this article](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/matrices_can_be_your_friends.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

The last is a perspective projection. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix